# Sum of average distance to sides of right triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let p be a point inside a right triangle. Draw in the shortest paths to each side of the triangle and sum up the lengths. What is the average of such sums over all interior points?

I solved the problem using calculus, but I'm wondering if there's a faster, elementary solution

$$ \frac{\int_0^b \int_0^{ax/b} \left(a-x + y+\frac{ax-by}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \right) \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x}{ab/2} = \frac{a}{3} + \frac{b}{3} + \frac{ab}{3c}$$

Somewhat related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_theorem

Comment: 1) Isn't it the "average of the sum" (in this order) ? 2) Hopefully [trilinear coordinates](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ybS3SaRS) or barycentric coordinates could provide a shortcut. I will think about it.

Comment: @JeanMarie average of the sum = sum of the average, so either is fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inside an not Equilateral Triangle what is the sum of distances from a random point to 3 sides](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631704/inside-an-not-equilateral-triangle-what-is-the-sum-of-distances-from-a-random-po)

Comment: Are a, b the sides that form the right angle? If yes edit the question.